# Redirect to a random entry from a list in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to be able to redirect a request to Nginx to a random entry from a list of possible options.

For example I want a request to `example.com/entryA` to be redirected to one of the following:

```
redirect.com/1
redirect.com/2
redirect.com/3
```

I know this is possible with proxy pass and a process that implements this logic, but I feel like that's overkill. Is this possible with Nginx without overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the easiest way to do this is with an Nginx instance with Lua installed (I used https://github.com/fabiocicerchia/nginx-lua)

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /entryA {
      content_by_lua_block {
        local redirects = {
          "http://redirect.com/1",
          "http://redirect.com/2",
          "http://redirect.com/3",
        }
        local random_url = redirects[math.random(1, #redirects)] 

        ngx.redirect(random_url)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```bash
$ curl http://localhost:80/entryA -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /entryA HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx/1.23.3
< Date: Sat, 01 Apr 2023 03:57:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 145
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://redirect.com/3
< 
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.23.3</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```